# Calling matlab from a bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, shell

I have a bash script that only calls matlab to see if it works but I get `matlab command not found`.

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab
```

I have this line in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Apps/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin
```

and when I type matlab into the terminal it opens as it should. Please, could someone explain how to fix this so I can use matlab in my scripts?

Thank you.

Comment: This should explain why it doesn’t work: https://superuser.com/a/183980

Comment: First: is /Apps/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab the correct path for the executable file (and if not, what does `type matlab` print)? Second, how is the script being run? With that `export` command in your .bash_profile, that `PATH` should be set for login shells, and things as subprocesses of login shells, but not in other contexts (e.g. in cron jobs).

Comment: @GordonDavisson - It is the correct path on my computer but `type matlab` returns `-bash: type: matlab: not found`. I am running the script using ./test.sh.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't follow that answer very well yet (newbie) but are you trying to say that the export line should be in ~/.bashrc instead?

Comment: Did you run `type matlab` in terminal, or in the script? If in the terminal, I'm very confused -- if `type` can't find it, it shouldn't work in a script, so something *really weird* is going on here.

Comment: In the terminal. If I use `alias matlab="/Apps/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab"` in my bash_profile then `type matlab` outputs `matlab is aliased to `/Apps/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab'` but if I remove the alias and just have `export PATH=$PATH:/Apps/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin/matlab` then `type matlab` doesn't find it. Maybe I am setting the environment variable wrong somehow?

Comment: @GordonDavisson If I use the full path name to matlab within my script then it works. Do you know how to properly set my environment so I would be able to just write `matlab ...` in my scripts like in my interactive shell? Thanks for your efforts so far.

Comment: `PATH` should include directories containing command binaries (e.g. /Apps/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin), *not* the executables themselves (e.g. /Apps/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab). Aliases aren't active in scripts; don't use that. Do be clear about the exact paths (in some places you have MATLAB_R2018**a**.app, in some places it's R2018**b**.app; which is correct?).

Comment: Yes, use `.bashrc`, the other file is not sourced in non-interactive shells.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks Cris.